# How to Get User Information From Google Search Console API

Tags: python-3.x, google-search-console

I wonder if I can get user information (such as email) by using the google search console API. I know I could get it with Google Analytics API but I wonder if this can be done with using only search console API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no way to get user information from google search console api. So I used *https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=token*. Token is the *'token'* key that exists in credentials json. Also you will need userinfo.email scope in order to get email of the user.

> 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'